# Save FormData to Indexdb

Tags: javascript, service-worker, indexeddb

The below code is what take final action to save the data to the target DB.

```
const onFileUpload = (e) => {
  const files = Array.from(e.target.files);
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('attachable_type', attachableType);
  formData.append('attachable_id', attachableId);

  if (files.length > 0) {
    const file = files[0];
    formData.append('file', file);

    upload(dispatch, {
      body: formData,
    }).then(() => {});
  }
};
```

Now I am building an offline app, where when no internet is available I would like to save this request to indexdb. I have the whole setup. All I want to know how can I save a `FormData` instance to indexdb so that I can later fetch it from indexdb and send it to server for permanent storage. I need some ideas. I tried some google but I don't see any direct answer to the following question. I am using `idb` npm plugin. The below update function I will be using to as an interface to talk to the db.

```
export async function update(attrs) {
  const db = await createAppDB();

  const tx = db.transaction('attachments', 'readwrite');
  const store = tx.objectStore('attachments');

  store.put(attrs);

  await tx.done;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extract the FormData through the [`Body.formData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/formData) method, and then retrieve its content by getting this FormData's entries and store these to IDB:

```js
(async () => {
  // in ServiceWorker while disconnected
  const request = buildRequest();
  // extract the FormData
  const fd = await request.formData();
  const serialized = {
    url: request.url,
    method: request.method,
    mode: request.mode,
    body: [ ...fd ]
    // you may need more fields from request
  };
  // you can now store the entries in IDB
  // here we just log it
  console.log( "stored", serialized );

  // and to build back the Request
  const retrieved = { ...serialized };
  const new_body = new FormData();
  for( let [ key, value ] of retrieved.body ) {
    new_body.append( key, value );
  }
  retrieved.body = new_body;
  const new_request = new Request( retrieved );
  // fetch( new_request );
  // remember to remove from IDB to avoid posting it multiple times
  console.log( "sent", [...new_body] );
} )();


// returns the same kind of Request object a ServiceWorker would intercept,
// whose body is a FormData
function buildRequest() {
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append( "some-key", "some-data" );
  fd.append( "the-file", new Blob( [ "hey" ] ), "file.txt" );
  return new Request( "", { method: "POST", body: fd } );
}
```

Too bad we can't just put POST requests in the Cache API, it would have been a lot cleaner...

Comment: Yes this is how I solved it in my case. Thanks for answering.

Comment: retrievedBody = cursor.value.body.reduce((fd,e) => (fd.append(...e),fd), new FormData());

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot store any FormData into IndexedDB directly. In my case, I had to implement photo uploading for an offline app. I saved images into IndexedDB in base64 format with some other data and then uploaded them on the server once the internet connection is restored.